# Run MySQL in RAM

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, ram

I have a moderately large database (~75 million rows, ~300 GB), and a fairly powerful machine (amazon r3.8xlarge, 32 CPUs, 244 GB RAM).  Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't seem to be using all this power.  It barely touches a tenth of the RAM.

My application of this database is a python program which reads the tables, crunches numbers, and stores results back in the database.  There's only one user, so no table locks are needed.

Ideally, nearly the entire database would be stored in RAM.  I considered mounting a straight RAM filesystem, but this means having to offload everything back to a hard drive myself.  I set the key_buffer_size and innodb_buffer_pool_size to 100G each, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: That seems like a bad idea when you encounter errors or power failures.

Comment: I know, but it's batch processing, in a data center, and the only way to eliminate the IO bottleneck.  I'll take the risk.

Comment: Does your program actually read or write enough data at a time to make all that RAM worthwhile? I would guess that maybe you need to work on improving the parallelism of your program before you throw more RAM at it. I bet the bottleneck right now isn't disk.

Comment: Did you measure the RAM usage on Python side? Pulling those large and maybe wide data frames or lists in memory and processing them I'd imagine would show a footprint.

Comment: There could be a number of things going on here. Mysql will cache data and indexes into RAM if it has the space, based the memory settings. But it generally doesnt store directly into ram outside of Memory tables. Its hard to know here, if mysql is the bottleneck or if its how the data is being read/accessed with python.

Comment: Check the MySQL error log on startup.  With `innodb_buffer_pool_size` set to 100G, you should see a message about "Initializing the InnoDB buffer pool" to that size, and `mysqld` should *immediately* eat 100G+ of RAM.  The buffer pool is a fixed allocation, claimed at startup.  If this isn't happening, you have an issue of the config file not being read.